# Isomorphism and free submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

Im given the following task: Let X be a free Z-Module with a basis containing of one element. Show that every submodul of X is free. Obviously X is isomorphic to Z. So if I assume X=Z the proof is fairly trivial. However, why does this then also apply for an arbitrary X? Isomorphisms are known for keeping the structure, but why exactly is this the case here? I don't immediately see it. Thank you in advance for answers!

Comment: Isomorphisms map submodules of the source onto submodules of the target, and vice-versa.

Comment: So if im given the isomorphism phi: Z-> X, then N is a submodule of Z exactly when phi(N) is a submodule of Z? This should then lead to N=(z1), so phi((z1))=(phi(z1)) which is a submodule and generated by one element. Is this correct?